# Where is better for render HTML when use NodeJS server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, frontend

If I want to serve web page that shows table of some contents, I have two option.

1. When client request page, Node server just response with JSON data and script for draw HTML table. And draw table in client side with Javascript.
2. When client request page, Node server render all of HTML code for table and response the code to client. So client will receive full HTML.

Which one is better way to render page? I have not enough skills about front-end so confuse what to do.

Comment: Which do you prefer? Sounds like #2.

Answer (score -2):

you can use reactjs in nodejs server exemple link:
https://medium.com/jspoint/a-beginners-guide-to-react-server-side-rendering-ssr-bf3853841d55

other link for render react app in server nodejs
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e/